# How to change Terminal opacity in Loki?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, release-loki

How can I change Terminal opacity in Loki? I have tried to change the font using dconf editor and it's work. But I couldn't do it for the opacity.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change it using an rgba color set.

For example, suppose you want to use solarized bg color. That has an hex value of #002b36, according to the [official website](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized), so it's equivalent is rgba(0,43,54,.95) which defines the same color with an opacity of .95. You can use the converter of your preference.

So, with dconf editor you should use the rgba value in the background option.